# How do I tell typescript once and for all that ResizeObserver is not always present on window?

Tags: typescript

I am using ResizeObserver with feature detection like this:

```
if ("ResizeObserver" in window) {
    // Use ResizeObserver
} else {
    window.addEventListener("resize", doFallBack(), {passive: true});
}
```

This gives a typescript error "TS2339: Property 'removeEventListener' does not exist on type 'never'".

I can solve this on a case by case basis, either with a ts-ignore comment or with `window as Partial<Window>`. However, I am wondering if I can tell typescript once and for all that ResizeObserver is not always present, since it isn't supported by older Safari versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can augment the `Window` interface and say that `ResizeObserver` should be optional:

```
interface Window {
    ResizeObserver?: ResizeObserver;
}

if ("ResizeObserver" in window) {
    // Use ResizeObserver
} else {
    window.addEventListener("resize", doFallBack(), {passive: true});
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOqgCYHsDuyDeAsAFDJnIBKEAzsAF4QDyARtdAG7QD8AXJTfSasO0ANwkAviRLAYyABQAiKrQYs2UTlEXJQyHJlwBKAiXLIA9BeQBVNv1VCNWycggAbe0VLkDIbDgAdHAYGACinOAAMsDUkCDQSlACDIoANMjYAGJw7u4AQogA1vJGGfgADnDUtJx8YFAArhASRuLEEkA)